# Evaluating limits via Infinite Series

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, limits, taylor-expansion

I am to evaluate the following limit of sums and quotients of infinite series

$\lim\limits_{z \to 0} \frac{(z^3 + z^6 - z^9 + ...)+(2z^3 -2 z^5 + 2z^7 - 2z^9 ...)}{z^8 + z^{16} + x^{24} + ... }$.

I canceled terms, in a peculiar manner.

The above limit becomes $\lim\limits_{z \to 0} \frac{-3z^9}{z^8}$
by cancelling every single term in the numerator except the $z^9$ terms.

Therefore, I reasoned 
$\lim\limits_{z \to 0} \frac{(z^3 + z^6 - z^9 + ...)+(2z^3 -2 z^5 + 2z^7 - 2z^9 ...)}{z^8 + z^{16} + x^{24} + ... }$ $=0$.

I feel I am incorrect, but I would like if you can steer me in a better direction.

Thank you,

Bayerischer

Comment: It's very hard to guess whether what you did is correct if you don't write down the general term in both summands in the numerator and in the denominator...What I can guess is that you can factor out $\;z^3\;$ in the numerator and $\;z^8\;$ in the denominator, and thus the limit wouldn't exist finitely...but this is only a wild guess. It is also very odd how did you "cancel" terms in the denominator: you already have $\;3z^3\;$ in that sum, so how did you cancel this?!

Comment: I zeroed-out every term except the $z^9$ term. And on the denominator, I zeroed-out every term after z^8.

Comment: You can't certainly do that! The limit seems to be inexistent but, again, without knowing more precisely what the sums are in numerators and denominators I can't say any more...

Comment: It is of the form 0/0, right?

Comment: It *seems to be*, yes...and if you're thinking of l'Hospital then you can already see that zero isn't, apparently, the limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$z$ tends to zero, so in the numerator, $3z^3$ is the dominant term, not $-3z^9$. So the limit is infinite.

**EDIT**: details requested:

$$
  \begin{align}
  &\lim_{z \to 0}
  \frac{(z^3 + z^6 - z^9 + ...)+(2z^3 -2 z^5 + 2z^7 - 2z^9 ...)}
       {z^8 + z^{16} + z^{24} + ... } \\
  &=
  \lim_{z \to 0}
  \frac{z^3}{z^8} \cdot
  \frac{(1 + z^3 - z^6 + ...)+(2 -2 z^2 + 2z^4 - 2z^6 ...)}
       {1 + z^{8} + z^{16} + ... } \\
  &=
  \lim_{z \to 0} \frac{3z^3}{z^8}
  \end{align}
$$

Comment: I checked with <numberempire.com> and indeed the limit is negative infinity.

Comment: Can you show the details?

Comment: I have already solved the enigma. Thank you.

Comment: @Bayerischer Just put it up anyway

Comment: I am sorry, I did not see your answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Bayerischer Sorry, I meant that "I had put it up anyway".